# Distributed File System For High Concurrent Access Of Small Files

Tags: filesystems, parallel-processing, hpc

what are the DFS technologies out there for high concurrent access (say by 10000 remote threads  on a local 1 gbs network) of 1,000,000 files which are only in MB size range but the DSF should provide high concurrent stream of them to users?

Answer (score 0):

Common HPC filesystems such as Lustre or GPFS often do not provide good support for the scenario you describe but are instead optimized towards high bandwidth on large file accesses. In the HPC context you should consider using IO middleware such as MPI-IO or high level IO libraries such as HDF5 rather than interfacing with the file system directly. Those libraries can hide the complexity of optimizing accesses to specific file systems from your application, which one is suitable depends on the structure of your application scenario.

On the other hand, for highly concurrent and unstructured small accesses, you might want to look into Cloud related technologies, e.g. Google Filesystem, distributed key value storages, Cassandra, just to give a few pointers for further research.

The general "file" abstraction and access approach (POSIX interface) was not designed for highly concurrent access which makes it difficult to conform with the interface and provide high concurrency at the same time.

If you want more specific hints for suitable technology, please provide some more specific information about your use-case(s).